# How to reconstruct sentences from these tokens

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a dataset like this.
The 1st column is the **word** and 2nd column is the **tag**.

> ```
> Pretty    O
> bad   O
> storm O
> here  O
> last  O
> evening   O
> . O
>
> From  O
> Green O
> Newsfeed  O
> : O
> AHFA  B-group
> extends   O
> deadline  O
> for   O
> Sage  O
> Award O
> to    O
> Nov   O
> . O
> ```

I want to reconstruct the sentences,

so the output will be like

```
[[('Pretty', 'O'), ('bad', 'O'), ('storm','O'), ('here', 'O'), ('last', 'O'), ('evening', 'O'), ('.', 'B-geo')][(From, 'O'), ('Green', 'O'), ('Newsfeed', 'O'), ('storm:,'O'), ('AHFA', 'B-group'), ('extends', 'O'), ('deadline', 'O'), ('for', 'O'),('Sage', 'O'), ('Award', 'B-geo')][(to, 'O'), ('Nov', 'O'), ('.','O']]
```

Can someone help me making the sentences from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have :

```
a = pd.DataFrame([('Pretty', 'O'), ('bad', 'O'), ('storm','O'), ('here', 'O'), ('last', 'O'), ('evening', 'O'), ('.', 'B-geo')])
```

then to get : `[('Pretty', 'O'), ('bad', 'O'), ('storm','O'), ('here', 'O'), ('last', 'O'), ('evening', 'O'), ('.', 'B-geo')]`

You can do :

```
[tuple(u) for u in a.values.tolist()]
```

Then you can do this for each one of your dataframe and concat all the list of tuple

If you have all your sentences in one dataframe like this :

```
a = pd.DataFrame([
('Pretty', 'O'), 
('bad', 'O'), 
('storm','O'), 
('here', 'O'), 
('last', 'O'), 
('evening', 'O'), 
('.', 'B-geo'), 
(' ',''),
('The', 'O'),
('World', 'O'),
('is', 'O'),
('...','N-geo')
])
```

you can find the index of " " ie space value and split your dataset like this :

```
index_list = a.index[a[0] == " "].tolist()
df1 = a.iloc[:index_list[0], :]
df2 = a.iloc[index_list[0]:, :]
```

So finally you'll have somethings like this :

```
def dataset_to_list_of_tuple(df):
    final_list = []
    index_list = df.index[df[0] == " "].tolist()
    for i in range(len(index_list)):
       if i == 0:
           df_part = df.iloc[:index_list[0], :]
       else:
           df_part = df.iloc[index_list[i-1]:index_list[i], :]
       sentence = [tuple(u) for u in df_part.values.tolist()]
       final_list.append(sentence)
   return final_list
```

Comment: There is only 1 dataframe, that contains all the explained value. I want to reconstruct sentences from that. The marke is '.' and there is '\n' after that.

Comment: Have you tried my last functin with df.index[df[0] == "\n"] instead of df.index[df[0] == " "]